# Could not start ASP.NET or ATL Server debugging

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7, windows-7, visual-studio-2003

I installed Visual Studio 2003 on Windows 7 but I am getting the following error on when I press the `F5` for debugging.

```
Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging on the web server. 
Could not start ASP.NET or ATL Server debugging.
Verify that ASP.NET or ATL Server is correctly installed on the server.
```

What does that mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The cause for this as per microsoft support is -

This problem occurs because the debugger does not send the debug action to IIS when you run the application. The debugger identifies your computer as localhost. However, in IIS, the Web Site Identification of the application is the IP address that you specified

The resolution is as given below -

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814717

http://forums.asp.net/t/703333.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found answer :

iis manager -> computer name -> ISAPI and CGI restrictions -> aspnet v1.1... -> select allowed

(dont forget restart IIS.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the options but in vain. My solution was:

1. Go to properties page of the application in VS2010
   a. check you have selected 'Define DEBUG constant'
   b. check you have selected 'Use Visual Studio development server' under the Server.
       i) select 'Auto-assign Port'
   c. check you have selected 'Apply server settings to all users'
   d. check you have selected 'asp.net' under Debuggers

Mine all the above were messy. I did the same and it worked.

Comment: Bare in mind that this is then not running the application with IIS, but [Cassini](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893391) (a different web server). It is quite a bit different and it's worth noting those differences :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to install another server on your computer, so it conflict with IIS server. You have to change another server port address or remove from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple steps to solve this error!!
Make sure the following things are intact:

1. Check if your application pool is **stopped**. If so, start it.
   Also make sure the framework of the pool matches with that of your application.
2. Virtual directories in IIS need to bear the **same name** as its
   original application directory
3. Clear Temp files, Temp ASP files, delete the worker process of the application and restart your IIS.

Here's a link that will help you setup ASP.Net 1.1 and its requisites, in case, the above didn't help you.
[How to setup asp.net v1.1](http://blogs.iis.net/brian-murphy-booth/archive/2007/03/09/how-to-setup-asp-net-v1-1-visual-studio-net-2003-projects-on-iis7-vista.aspx)